# Raspberry Pi 3 - sound and microphone doesn't work

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have installed Raspbian Jessie with Pixel (version April 2017) on my Raspberry Pi 3. I have plugged a Platronics C320-M headphone + microphone set.
And obviously it doesn't work.
I have followed this instructions: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-do-i-configure-my-sound-for-jasper-on-raspbian-jessie/40832
to make my USB set a main device.
So no I have:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/asound/modules 
 0 snd_usb_audio
 1 snd_bcm2835

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
# This sets the index value of the cards but doesn't reorder.
options snd_usb_audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1

# Does the reordering.
options snd slots=snd_usb_audio,snd_bcm2835

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: C320M [Plantronics C320-M], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But when I try to play test sound:

```
speaker-test -c2 -twav
```

I can see test running but can't hear anything.
Really have no idea what to check/set more...
I will be grateful for any hints.

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

try to follow below steps to enable audio recording and playback from a usb-sound adapter for rpi-3. I had documented these while performing audio recording from usb sound adapter. Hope this help you.

- Steps:

1.1) Create/edit file .asoundrc

```
$vim .asoundrc
```

If file is not present create it;

```
$ touch .asoundrc

$vim .asoundrc 
pcm.!default {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "hw:1,0"
        capture.pcm "hw:1,0"
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

1.2)Edit below line in file alsa.conf;

```
$sudo vim /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

to

```
$sudo vim /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

1.3) Change audio levels/setting using alsamixer utility

```
$alsamixer
```

1.4) Command to record audio

```
$arecord -D plughw:1 -f S16_LE -r 48000 -d 5 ./testSound.wav
```

1.5) Command to play recorded audio

```
$aplay --device=plughw:1,0 ./testSound.wav
```